# Finding which test cases are getting skipped in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

If you could see in below picture, there are 98 skipped test . Could any one suggest me how should we see the skipped tests in Jenkins. As Test results in Jenkins is showing only Failed tests.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blue Ocean shows the skipped tests in addition to the failed tests.

https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/